# Solving linear non-homogeneous integral equation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible to solve equations of the kind:

$$x(t) = \int \limits_t^T c_1  x(s) ds +c_2 $$ with $c_1$ and $c_2$ being some constants and if I know $x(0)$?

Or do I need more assumptions on $x$?

Comment: Do you know about ordinary differential equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hint***:

what about differentiating both sides and solving for $x(t)$ (provided $x(t)$ is differentiable - thanks to @LiuGang for pointing out)? You will need to recall that:

> $$ \color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} \int^t_{a} f(s)  \, \mathrm{d}s =f(t), \quad a \in \mathbb{R}}$$

and, of course, that:

> $$\color{blue}{ x'(t) + c \, x = 0 \implies x(t) = x_0 e^{-c  t}, \quad x_0 = x(t=0)}$$

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

---

***Question***: will there be any relation between $c_2$ and $T$?

Comment: Since OP doesn't say explicitly $x(t)$ is differentiable, we need first point out $x(t)$ is continuous due to the integral form, then continuous integrand leads to continuously differentiable

Comment: You are certainly right. My answer is therefore partial, so to speak, and it only tries to show the methods/techniques underlying solving this kind of equations.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, Dmoreno and @LiuGang! I think the fact that I am feeling really stupid after reading the answer is an indicator of a really great answer. Thanks!